# Admob not shown

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to add AdMob in an app i've developed.

This is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        googleads:adSize="BANNER"
        googleads:adUnitId="###########" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my code in onCreate method:

```
//ads
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

LogCat gives something like:

```
Received ad url <url: http://googleads.....
```

So it's somehow working, but on my app, i never see any banner. Do you've any idea what is happening?

I've followed this tutorial:
http://androcode.es/2012/05/monetizando-nuestras-apps-admob-en-android/
Aswel as http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/monetization/ads-and-ux.html

But none with luck.

**Edit:**
Oh, forgot to mention that I've those two lines in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

For instance, if I remove any of those permissions, the AD is **SHOWN** saying that there's some permissions missing. So I think layout is fine.

**Edit2:**
Also tried to set this code for testing purposes and it's happening exactly the same:

```
adRequest.addTestDevice("#############");
```

**Edit3:**
I've read that it might take long first time. How long might it take? Because I've waited for about 30 minutes. Would logcat say that it received ad anyways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Apparently its working on emulator:
added this on the xml file:

```
googleads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
```